# What's the purpose of Twig "include with only"?

Tags: symfony, twig

What's really the purpose of `include with only` in Twig:

```
{# only the foo variable will be accessible #}
{% include 'child.html.twig' with {'foo': 'bar'} only %}
```

Maybe some **performance** benefits? Or just only for avoid **overriding variables** in the included template? As [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html):

> *Included templates have access to the variables of the active context. You can disable access to the context by appending the only keyword.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you include a template, it has access to all the variables available in the including template. If for some reason you don't want that, use the `only` keyword.

I haven't been in a situation when I needed that, but there might be reasons other than performance. For example, you could use it to avoid naming collisions in some scenarios.