# symfony2 - twig - how to render a twig template from inside a twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a xxx.html.twig file which shows a page, but when I want to refresh the page with different data and just update it with new data, I have a select and a submit button for it.
The thing is that I don't know how do I call an action in the controller which I pass parameters to from my twig and call for new data and then I render the same twig template again with new parameters.

How do I do so?

Comment: You can only do this using a new request. If you don't want to load the whole page, have a look at Ajax.

Comment: You should extend your question with code examples and specify places, where you want pass what

Comment: @Sgoettschkes, I want to reload the whole page with new data array, how do I do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Symfony 2.1:

```
{% render 'YourBundle:YourController:yourAction' with {'var': value} %}
```

## Symfony 2.6+:

```
{{ render(controller('YourBundle:YourController:yourAction', {'var': value})) }}
```

And, of course, read the [documentation.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)

Comment: Variable "select1" does not exist in

Comment: That is deprecated, replaced with `{{ render(controller('SomeBundle:SomeController:someAction', { 'someVariable': someValue })) }}`.

Comment: As @Oltarus suggest, the render function needs parentheses: render( controller (...) )

Answer (score 41):

Here are a few different ways:

```
{{ render(app.request.baseUrl ~ '/helper/test', {"hostid2": hostid } ) }}
```

or

```
{% include 'MyCoreBundle:Helper:test.html.twig' with {"hostid2": hostid } only %}
```

or

```
{% render controller("MyCoreBundle:Helper:test", {'hostid2': hostid}) %}
```

Comment: could you explain briefly what the `only` at the end of the `include` is for please?

Comment: Nevermind, I've found a good explaination here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9935551/4074148

Comment: Ahh love between mans :)   I've found a bug trying to do: 
   {# any for loop #}
   {{ render(app.request.baseUrl ~ '/helper/test', {"hostid2": forloop.var } ) }}
   {# endfor #}

Even that the different values get inside the rendered controller, in the final template, they do not change. I'm tearing my white hairs out with this one.

Comment: Note that `{% render %}` is now deprecated, it is replaced by `{{ render() }}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think some parts are depricated here.
To make the include work in latest Symfony 3.1.10, I solved it like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    {{ include('AppBundle:Default:inner_content.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Note: include() with parentheses.
Then all the variables are included from the parent template. If you like to restrict some variables in the child template, you use with ... only (look over)